# Gradle compilation ordering issue with mixed Java/Groovy source

Tags: spring, groovy, gradle

I'm having an issue with compilation ordering in a mixed Java/Groovy environment. We're using Gradle 2.1, JDK 7, and Groovy 2.3. The code compiles fine in STS (Spring Tool Suite), using the Gradle plugin and the same build.gradle files, but fails when the build is run on the command line. STS is configured to use the Groovy Eclipse plugin, which if I understand things correctly, uses its own compiler. So I think this problem stems from a compilation ordering problem when we use the Groovy compiler from Gradle's Groovy plugin. This is the Groovy class:

```
@Component
@ToString(includeNames = true, includePackage = false)
class ManagedCloseableHttpClientFactory implements ClientHttpRequestFactory {
  @Delegate
  HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory
...
}
```

The ClientHttpRequestFactory is a Spring interface that is implemented by the Spring class HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory. Somewhere else in the system, we have a Java class annotated with @Configuration, where the ManagedCloseableHttpClientFactory is injected using @Autowired. Like this:

```
@Configuration
public class FooConfiguration {
  @Autowired
  private ManagedCloseableHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;
...
}
```

When the build is run from the command line, we get the following error message: **/Users/xyz/source/prj/common/build/tmp/compileGroovy/groovy-java-stubs/common/web/client/ManagedCloseableHttpClientFactory.java:10: error: ManagedCloseableHttpClientFactory is not abstract and does not override abstract method createRequest(URI,HttpMethod) in ClientHttpRequestFactory**. If we move the field marked with @Autowired to a Groovy class that is annotated with @Configuration, everything works, but not when it's declared inside a Java class. I'm guessing that this is a compilation ordering issue. In our Gradle files, we're using the groovy plugin, and have modified the source directories as follows:

```
project.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []
project.sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = []
project.sourceSets.main.groovy.srcDirs = ["src/main/java", "src/main/groovy"]
project.sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs  += ["config"]
project.sourceSets.test.groovy.srcDirs += ["src/test/java","src/test/groovy"]
```

What's the best approach here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Groovy compiler's stub generator has some limitations. My best guess is that you can't have Java call a Groovy method materialized by `@Delegate`. I'd try to get rid of this particular Java->Groovy dependency or this particular usage of `@Delegate` (i.e. implement the delegation by hand).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is this limitation documented somewhere? Do you know if there are any plans on addressing this limitation from the Groovy dev folks? How come the Groovy-Eclipse compiler manages it but not the one bundled with the Groovy release? It would be nice to be able to use the same compiler for Eclipse/STS and the command line. The beauty of using Gradle to build is that I don't have to manage Eclipse build configs separately. But with the two Groovy compiler flavors, I run into issues like this from time to time.

Comment: I'm not aware of any documentation for the stub generator's limitations. There are concrete plans to implement stubless joint compilation for the reference compiler, but I don't know when this feature will ship (best ask the Groovy folks). Groovy Eclipse will probably always have its own joint compiler which integrates with the Eclipse Java compiler. (Eclipse doesn't use the JDK Java compiler.)

Comment: Thanks for your response Peter. Do you know if there's a way of using the Groovy Eclipse compiler from Gradle? Would there be any serious drawbacks with that approach? From my naive end user point of view, I just want the code to compile as smoothly as it does from Eclipse.

Comment: Currently, Gradle only supports the reference compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If possible inject the interface instead of the concrete class. Since the injection happens on run time the class will be full created then, and in compile time compiler will recognize the interface as having all the required fields.

```
@Configuration
public class FooConfiguration {
  @Autowired
  private ClientHttpRequestFactory httpClientFactory;
...
}
```